# How to fix choppy Bluetooth audio in Windows 10 Boot Camp with MacBook Pro?

Tags: bootcamp, audio, windows, bluetooth

I have the following hardware and software:

- MacBook Pro 2017 (`MacBookPro14,2`)
- Windows 10 Pro (`10.0.18363 Build 18363`)
- [1Mii B06 Plus Bluetooth Receiver](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B078J3GTRK)
- [B&O PLAY by Bang & Olufsen Beoplay H8i Wireless Bluetooth On-Ear Headphones](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07N53XCWM)

And when connecting to *any* Bluetooth audio device, the sound is choppy, (or for SEO: patchy, laggy, interrupted) in exactly the same way for each device. The sound will "pop" every 1-3 seconds, followed by a short 0.1-0.3s gap in the sound.

I also have to completely unpair and re-pair any Bluetooth audio devices every time Windows is booted, just to get it working in the first place.

I was able to boot in to Windows once where the audio worked perfectly, without any choppiness. But I haven't been able to reproduce that ideal scenario.

This installation of Windows 10 Pro is extremely clean and only a week old.

**Here are a list of solutions that I've tried:**

1. [Enabling "Bluetooth Calibration" or just disabling wifi altogether](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7595720): Someone said that the wifi is likely interfering with the Bluetooth, and to enable "Bluetooth Calibration" for the wifi adapter. I couldn't find that feature, but I figured disabling the wifi adapter completely would fix the issues. The audio still *chops* with wifi disabled.
2. [Closing the "Manage Bluetooth" screen](https://jonleigh.me/fixing-stuttering-bluetooth-audio-on-windows-10-under-bootcamp/): This helped make the choppiness less frequent, but it still occurs. From Jon Leigh's solution, where he says:

> *Joris reported below that he's getting the same issue on his windows PC that isn't running under Bootcamp! So the issue is more widespread than first thought. Poor show Microsoft!*

3. [Disabling Bluetooth "Avrcp Transport" devices](https://superuser.com/a/1362002/2373): This only works if there are multiple conflicting devices. Disabling the only "Avrcp Transport" device that corresponds to the Bluetooth audio device being used will just disable the audio altogether.
4. [Running the System File Checker tool](https://superuser.com/a/1472183/2373): I ran various file system checkers, mentioned in Microsoft's guide: [Use the System File Checker tool to repair missing or corrupted system files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system):

```
    PS C:\> DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth

    Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
    Version: 10.0.18362.1

    Image Version: 10.0.18363.778

    [==========================100.0%==========================]
    The restore operation completed successfully.
    The operation completed successfully.
```

```
    PS C:\> sfc /scannow

    Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

    Beginning verification phase of system scan.
    Verification 100% complete.

    Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.

      5. [Update Bluetooth drivers][8]: Windows says "The best drivers for your device are already installed", so it has no effect.
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to buy a USB Bluetooth adapter.

Nothing else worked, including avoiding using 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi.